# '&LTV' rendering as '<V' when I need it to literally say '&LTV' - php

Tags: php

I ran into a quirky syntax issue.

I am using php and cUrl to pull in data from a web page. The link has several variables. One of them is '&LTV', but the resulting link keeps translating `'&LTV'` as `'<V'`, looking as `'&LT'` and the 'less than' symbol, when I need the literal text.

I have looked all over the place to figure out how to force php to read '&LTV' literally but have not found it.

Any ideas here would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `&LT` turning into `<` shouldn't be occurring, since that's an invalid entity. it should be `&lt;`, WITH a semicolon. `echo html_entity_decode('&lt &lt;')` produces `&lt <` as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your HTML entities. Either use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or manually type out the string `"&amp;LTV"`.

Comment: thanks ... but for anybody else, when checking the link for cUrl purposes, when echoing to the web browser, the &lt part of &ltv did render as '<v', but when i sent the link with the '&amp;ltv=' to the cUrl, it reads it literally. So I went back to the raw '&ltv=' and the cUrl recognized the link.